# by clicking on one button invoke two other buttons

Tags: xpages

I would like by clicking on a button to "activate" the clicking of 2 other buttons.
I've put this ccjs in the onclick event:

```
document.getElementById("#{id:button28}").click();document.getElementById("#{id:button29}").click();
```

But then only button 28 gets clicked !
Then I tried putting this part1 of the code under the onclick event and part2 under the onmousedown event. Then I have to click 2 times this button before he actually does the job.

the code so far:

```
<xp:button value="Save" id="button26">
<xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
    <xp:this.script>
        <xp:executeClientScript>
    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[document.getElementById("#{id:button29}").click();
    ></xp:this.script>
        </xp:executeClientScript>
    </xp:this.script></xp:eventHandler></xp:button><xp:button id="button29" value="button29">
    <xp:eventHandler
    event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial"
    id="eventHandler21" refreshId="outsidePanel5">
        <xp:this.action>
            <xp:actionGroup>
                <xp:executeScript>
                <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:sessionScope.put("test","");// and some more code}]]>
                </xp:this.script>
                </xp:executeScript>
            </xp:actionGroup>
        </xp:this.action>
    <xp:this.onComplete><![CDATA[document.getElementById("#{id:button28}").click();]]></xp:this.onComplete>
    </xp:eventHandler></xp:button><xp:button value="button28" id="button28">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="outsideMogelijkheid">
        <xp:this.action>
            <xp:executeScript
                    script="#{javascript://some code}">
            </xp:executeScript>
        </xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these buttons execute SSJS code you need to add the code to click on the second button in the 
onComplete event of the first button.

http://xpagesblog.com/XPagesHome.nsf/Entry.xsp?documentId=0574D334CB03EACF852578CB00667F54

**Addition**
Working example of onComplete not that it **only works with partial refresh**

```
<xp:button value="Save" id="button26">
<xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[document.getElementById("#{id:button29}").click()]]>
</xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
<xp:button id="button29" value="button29">

<xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
    refreshMode="partial" refreshId="computedField1">

    <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.test="Almost Done"}]]>
</xp:this.action>
    <xp:this.onComplete>
<![CDATA[document.getElementById("#{id:button28}").click();]]>
</xp:this.onComplete>
    <xp:this.onError><![CDATA[alert("error")]]></xp:this.onError>
</xp:eventHandler></xp:button>

<xp:button value="button28" id="button28">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" 
refreshMode="partial" refreshId="computedField1">

        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[alert("Button 28")]]></xp:this.script>
        <xp:this.action>
            <xp:executeScript>
                <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.test="Done"}]]>
</xp:this.script>
            </xp:executeScript>
        </xp:this.action></xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
<xp:br></xp:br>
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1" value="#{viewScope.test}"></xp:text>
```

Comment: I don't think I understand what to do. I tried the following : In the oncomplete event of the first button I've put document.getElementById("#{id:button28}").click(); So in the sourcepanel I get : <xp:this.onComplete><![CDATA[document.getElementById("#{id:button28}").click();]]></xp:this.onComplete> This gives an error that he can't find the value of the click property.

Comment: Could you post an xpage source with your problem then I can correct the source.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run the SSJS in another button, you can actually call the eventHandler programmatically rather than triggering the button in CSJS. This will also perform better, because you're not switching between CSJS and SSJS all the time. The following code should work:

```
var eventHandler:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspEventHandler = getComponent("button29");
eventHandler.getAction().invoke(facesContext, null);
eventHandler = getComponent("button28");
eventHandler.getAction().invoke(facesContext, null);
```

Comment: As a better way, use component binding, see http://www.intec.co.uk/triggering_an_eventhandler_from_another_button/