# How can i invoke an event handler of control A from the control B?

Tags: events, xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have 2 comboBoxes in my XPage. Combo A and Combo B. Combo A has an event handler onChange. When i change combo B value i want to invoke Combo A onChange event so as to execute a code that exists there and avoid duplicating it into combo B event.

So in onChange event of combo B i want to invoke onChange event of combo A.

I dont mind if i have to change combo A value. In fact i tried to do so with CSJS and SSJS but the onChange event of A did not fire although the value was changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this on client side. I am using the following JS function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5012297/1167922).

```
// itemId : ID of an element
// eventName: The name of the event (change, click, etc.)
function fireEvent(itemId, eventName) {
    var item=dojo.byId(itemId);

    if(item) {
        if (dojo.isIE) {
            // IE does things differently
            item.fireEvent("on"+eventName);
        }
        else { 
            // Not IE
            var event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
            event.initEvent(eventName, false, true); // Last two arguments: bubbles, cancelable
            item.dispatchEvent(event);
        }
    } else {
        console.log("'"+itemId+"' does not exist!");    
        // Item does not exist! 
    }
}
```

However there is a tricky part for XPages. If your combo box is triggering a server-side event you should call this function at onComplete. Otherwise you can put a client-side script. For instance:

```
<xp:comboBox
    id="targetComboBox"
    value="#{viewScope.TargetCombo}">
<!-- Some select items here -->
</xp:comboBox>

<xp:comboBox
    id="comboBox1"
    value="#{viewScope.Combo1}">
    <xp:selectItem
        itemLabel="Value1.1"
        itemValue="1.1">
    </xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem
        itemLabel="Value1.2"
        itemValue="1.2">
    </xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem
        itemLabel="Value1.3"
        itemValue="1.3">
    </xp:selectItem>
    <xp:eventHandler
        event="onchange"
        submit="false">
        <xp:this.script>
            <xp:scriptGroup>
                <xp:executeClientScript script="console.log('combo1 changed');"></xp:executeClientScript>
                <xp:executeClientScript script="fireEvent('#{id:targetComboBox}', 'change')"></xp:executeClientScript>
            </xp:scriptGroup>
        </xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:comboBox>

<xp:comboBox
    id="comboBox2"
    value="#{viewScope.Combo1}">
    <xp:selectItem
        itemLabel="Value2.1"
        itemValue="2.1">
    </xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem
        itemLabel="Value2.2"
        itemValue="2.2">
    </xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem
        itemLabel="Value2.3"
        itemValue="2.3">
    </xp:selectItem>
    <xp:eventHandler
        event="onchange"
        submit="true"
        refreshMode="norefresh"
        onComplete="fireEvent('#{id:targetComboBox}', 'change')">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:print("combo2 changed")}]]></xp:this.action>
        <xp:this.script>
            <xp:scriptGroup>
                <xp:executeClientScript script="console.log('combo2 changed');"></xp:executeClientScript>
            </xp:scriptGroup>
        </xp:this.script></xp:eventHandler>
</xp:comboBox>
```

In this example, combo1 has its own CSJS event and combo2 has one SSJS and one CSJS event. Both are triggering the targetComboBox...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a duplicate of this question. You can also do it server-side, see my answer there. Testing it again now, getComponent needs to get the EventHandler component, not the Button component, so you need to add an ID to the eventHandler you want to call and call getComponent on that

Comment: Sorry, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069883/by-clicking-on-one-button-invoke-two-other-buttons

Comment: There's a better way http://www.intec.co.uk/triggering_an_eventhandler_from_another_button/